# Python sorting complexity on sorted list

Tags: python, sorting

What is the `sort(already_sorted_list)` complexity in Python? Does Python check if given iterable is sorted, or do I have to do it by myself? I could not find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Now I need to look up the full implementation of the Tim-Sort algorithm.  The answer though is yes, it does some look-ahead comparison to determine if something is already sorted, or almost sorted.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: There is a great [wiki entry](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) that discusses the time complexity of many Python functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *entirely* implementation dependent.  All that python guarantees is that the builtin sorting algorithm is *stable* (elements which compare equal retain their relative ordering).  An implementation could even use a stable bubble sort if it wanted to ...

Cpython uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (a hybrid of insertion sort an mergesort) which I believe has O(N) complexity if the input is already sorted -- It picks up the best case performance of insertion sort and the worst case performance of mergesort (O(NlogN)).

And if you're curious about the implementation, the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/33a39dfc239e/Objects/listsort.txt) has a very nice description.

Comment: Best case scenario: O(n), average and worst case O(nlogn).

Comment: Crucially, this means that applying `sorted` to a sorted list is *as efficient as checking that it's sorted beforehand*.

Answer (score 1):

Python's sort is called [timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Its average case performance is O(nlog(n)). It performs really well with pre-sorted lists because it's implementation is designed to seek out runs of sorted elements in the list.