# How to use the IF ALL statement in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a function named checker(nums) that has an argument that will later receive a list. What i want to do with that list is to check if each other element is greater or equal to the previous one.
Example:
I have a list `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` and i have to check if it fulfills the condition.
Since it does, the function should return `True`

My code:

```
def checker(nums):
    for x in range(len(nums)):
        if x+1<len(nums):
            if nums[x] <= nums[x+1] and nums[-1] >= nums[-2]:
                return True
```

This will only run once and return True if the first condition is true.
I've seen a statement if all and am unsure of how to use it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your function can be reduced to this:

```
def checker(nums):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

Note the following:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) loops through its arguments in parallel, i.e. `nums[0]` & `nums[1]` are retrieved, then `nums[1]` & `nums[2]` etc.
- `i <= j` performs the actual comparison.
- The [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) denoted by parentheses `()` ensures that each value of the condition, i.e. `True` or `False` is extracted one at a time. This is called *lazy evaluation*.
- [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) simply checks all the values are `True`. Again, this is lazy. If one of the values extracted lazily from the generator expression is `False`, it short-circuits and returns `False`.

#### Alternatives

To avoid the expense of building a list for the second argument of `zip`, you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). This option is particularly useful when your input is an iterator, i.e. it cannot be sliced like a `list`.

```
from itertools import islice

def checker(nums):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in zip(nums, islice(nums, 1, None)))
```

Another iterator-friendly option is to use the [`itertools` `pairwise` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available via 3rd party [`more_itertools.pairwise`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/more_itertools/recipes.html#pairwise):

```
# from more_itertools import pairwise  # 3rd party library alternative
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def checker(nums):
    return all(i <= j for i, j in pairwise(nums))
```

Another alternative is to use a functional approach instead of a comprehension:

```
from operator import le

def checker_functional(nums):
    return all(map(le, nums, nums[1:]))
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code can in fact be reduced to checking if `nums` is sorted, e.g.

```
def checker(nums):
    return sorted(nums) == nums
```

This does exactly what you expect, e.g.

```
>>> checker([1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
True
>>> checker([1, 1, 2, 2, 1])
False
```

Comment: Downside is that this solution is O(N log N). Upside is simplicity

Comment: This is only partially true. If the list is sorted, this is in fact only O(n), see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809785/python-sorting-complexity-on-sorted-list. But sure, the worst case complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: You're wrong,  that's not "partially true", I only referred to Worst Case. I never once talked about best case or average case. If I was talking about best case I would have used the correct symbol. And the reason why we are doing this check is because sometimes the list is not sorted, therefore it is O(N log N)

Answer (score 3):

Similar solution to @jp_data_analysis using [`more_itertools.windowed`](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed)

```
>>> from more_itertools import windowed
>>> nums = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> all(i <= j for i, j in windowed(nums, 2))
True
```

---

And for scientific purposes (not recommended code), here is a more functional approach

```
>>> from operator import le
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> all(starmap(le, windowed(nums, 2)))
True
```