# Difference in performance of sorted(reverse=True) and [::-1]

Tags: python, list, sorting

In Python, what is the difference in performance of these two methods for sorting in reverse order?

For example if I have a list `arr`, then if I do

`sorted(arr, reverse=True)`
or

`arr[::-1]`

then which one is faster for large size of `arr`?

Also how both of these perform in comparison to `arr.sort(reverse=True)`?

I want to know this to minimize execution time during competitive programming

Comment: these are not equivalent commands and they will not yield the same result unless the original list is already sorted. It's not correct to compare execution time.

Comment: Okay so let's assume the list is already sorted normally and then if I want to reverse it?

Comment: Sorting an already sorted list can lead to a worst case scenario. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809785/python-sorting-complexity-on-sorted-list

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same:

- `arr[::-1]`: Reverse the list
- `sorted(arr, reverse=True)`: Perform a sort of the list in reverse order

```py
>>> arr = [1, 7, 5]
>>> arr[::-1]
[5, 7, 1]
>>> sorted(arr, reverse=True)
[7, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. What if the list is already sorted in first case and I just need to reverse it?

Comment: Then```arr[::-1]``` @SamakshKhatri